# dropping into a draggable with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to drop a draggable div into an already draggable and droppable div with jquery? I just cannot achieve this. I would be grateful if somebody could give a working example.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
What I cannot achieve is a div into which different divs can be dropped and they can be sorted. Furthermore, these dropped and sortable divs should also at the same time be able to accommodate again sortable and dropable divs.

**EDIT**
What I'm trying to make work is at : http://jsfiddle.net/QcbK8/

Comment: So each div can be a child of another and you need to implement sortable within each set, be it the global parent, or inside a child?  I assume there is no limit to the depth?

Answer (score 0):

How about:  [threedub](http://threedubmedia.com/demo/drop/), built on jQuery.

Comment: In this example, what I'm wondering is adding A into B (where both A and B are still both droppable).

Comment: Ah!  Sorry for the confusion!  http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/ has lots of places to start, but not exactly that.

Comment: Great examples, thanks! However non of them perform the effect I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

just because an element is draggable does not mean it can not be droppable as well.

I have written a little example for you, it's very trivial, half the elements are drop only, red borders, half are drop targets *and* draggable too.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/63kgz/1/

**HTML:** *(a few random objects)*

```
<div class="drag"><span>A</span></div>
<div class="drag"><span>B</span></div>
<div class="drag"><span>C</span></div>
<br class="clear" />
<div class="drop"><span>D</span><p></p></div>
<div class="drop"><span>E</span><p></p></div>
<div class="drop"><span>F</span><p></p></div>
```

**CSS:** *(ignore this, it's just to show up random objects)*

```
.drag { width: 100px; height: 100px;
        float:left; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 10px;
        border:1px solid #f00;
}
.drop { width: 200px; height: 200px;
        float:left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
}
.drop p { width: auto;
          color: #00f;
          margin-left: 50%; margin-right: 50%; margin-top: 25%; margin-bottom: 25%;
}
.clear { clear: both; }
div {
    user-select: none;
   -o-user-select:none;
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Everything is draggable
$('.drag,.drop').draggable();

// Only the .drop class is droppable
$('.drop').droppable({
    'accept': '.drag,.drop',
    'drop' : function(event, ui) {
        $(this).find('p').text(ui.draggable.find('span').text());
    }
});

// This just makes the sizes different so the objects fit in each other
$('.drag').css('width', function(i, value) {
    return parseInt(value) * (1 / (i + 1)) + 'px';
}).css('height', function(i, value) {
    return parseInt(value) * (1 / (i + 1)) + 'px';
});
$('.drop').css('width', function(i, value) {
    return parseInt(value) * (1 / (i + 1)) + 'px';
}).css('height', function(i, value) {
    return parseInt(value) * (1 / (i + 1)) + 'px';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have refined my question to be more relevant to what I want to achieve.

Comment: @No1 You did not mention Sortable previously and I did wonder if you meant DIVs becoming part of the drop target.  Have you seen the Photo Manager example on jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: Yes, sorry you are right I did not mention that. Thank you so much for your help. I did see that example. What I'm trying to do (in terms of that example) is inserting photos inside the photos inside the trash in a sortable way.

Comment: @No1 Something I am playing with at the moment, as an example (no sortable yet, and haven't got the CSS under control to grow things properly when embedded - hopefully I'll come back to it later if I have time, might give some ideas): http://jsfiddle.net/hYzhC/

Comment: @No1 The problem I have with my new example is CSS-related, as opposed to the mechanics.  Do you already have your structure setup?

Comment: @Orbling yes I do have a structure setup: http://jsfiddle.net/QcbK8/ the problem is dragging the inner_draggable divs into drag_item_container divs. It would be great if you could take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @No1 If I get a "free" moment at work `(WHERE "free" = isOutside(boss))` - then I'll look over it this afternoon.

Comment: @No1 Had a look at your code.  From what I can tell the idea is, there are a load of draggables, and a droppable to start with.  If an item is dropped in a droppable, it becomes part of it, enters into the parents sortable, and it becomes a droppable itself.  Is that right?

Comment: @Orbling What I want to do is make a horizontal or vertical div container that can receive other divs in a sortable way.